# how to use trigger and cursor?

Tags: mysql, wamp, innodb, wampserver

I am a newbie here. I am doing a college project where there is a database keeping the informations of recruitement drive. I have 2 tables called ghlead_create_drive and genmgr_approve_drive. Now I would like to check that while inserting a data in genmgr_approve_drive it should check with the data of ghlead_create_drive.

The structure of the ghlead_create_drive is

```
( event_id int(8), ghlead_id int(8), create_date date)
```

and genmgr_approve_drive is

```
( event_id int (8), genmgr_id int(8) approve_date date).
```

I have to check that approve_date mast be greater than create_date ... or create_date is earlier than approve_date.

Now after googling I came to know that I can use trigger and cursor select dataset from a table and compare it before inserting. But I am not getting a clear idea about how to check the create_date and the date that we inserted in a form.

What is the NEW data and OLD data that we use in trigger?

Thanking you. and pardon me if I am wrong in somewhere.

Comment: can't you just implement a check in whatever program you're using to access the DB, so it doesn't run the insert with invalid data in the first place?

Comment: Yea but my guess is (s)he would like you to write it for them! **This is not a free coding service** Its a help with a specific coding issue site. So try it yourself then ask for help on a specific issue if you get stuck.